# When I add a grid "Layout" the units don't match with my map's

Tags: qgis, layouts, grids-graticules

When I add a Grid in Layout and select "Map units" and Interval the units still don't match[image: The map units is meters, so there should be a grid every 400 km]

[image]

Comment: That metres is for the radius of the ellipsoid, not your map